Pnpm workspace config to publish pakcages under a specific directory only
I have created a monorepo, and the folder structure is like the below screenshot.
Currently, if I run pnpm publish in the root directory, it will publish the root project pnpm-trial and all the libs under packages directory, which is not what I expected.
I want to only publish all the packages(common, my-ui-library) under the packages folder, how can I do it?
BTW, you can think my package name is the same as the directory name in this example.


It seems we can use --filter to achieve it:
pnpm --filter \"./packages/**\" publish

https://pnpm.io/filtering
